# How can I make it so that users can add content to my site?

Tags: nodes

I have created a custom content type for my site that takes three fields. I then created a view that displays only that content type in a grid form. I need to know how to allow users to add content based in the form of my custom content type so that they can add things that will directly be added to the custom view I made. (Essentially the view makes a grid that displays rows of 3 images in each row. The images when clicked on will then take the user to a page that gives a description of what the image is along with a few other things.) Does anyone know what I can do with this, or if there is a much easier way to do this that I am totally missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can I suggest editing your question a bit? I think you're providing way too much superfluous information.  I believe your question is: "How do I let anonymous users submit content?" is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You only have to provide access to anonymous user to add content for the content type that you have created. For that go to permission page of Drupal:

> admin/people/permissions

Check the following check boxes for anonymous user.

> Basic (your content type) page: Create new content
>
> Basic(your content type) page: Edit own content

Comment: But bear in mind that if you let anonymous users post content, then assuming this is a public site you will have a massive problem with spam. You can set the content type to be unpublished by default, but then someone will have to review the submissions before publishing them.

Answer (score 0):

[Content access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) is the module you need, this module helps handling content type permission, nice and clean.

> This module allows you to manage permissions for content types by role
>   and author. It allows you to specifiy custom view, edit and delete
>   permissions for each content type. Optionally you can enable per
>   content access settings, so you can customize the access for each
>   content node.

Comment: No, I don't think OP needs that here. Drupal core allows you to control create permissions for each content type.

Answer (score 0):

For the content type that has the fields on it, allow the `anonymous` user role the ability to create new nodes. This is located at `/admin/people/permissions`.